# PHP didn't receive file from JAVA app

Tags: php, file-upload

A Java app which I can't modify is sending a csv file to my PHP script via a `POST` request. `$_POST` and `$_FILES` are empty.

Max file size are set `5Mb` and my file don't exceed it.

Here is the wireshark dump of the Java app's request:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFX6z.jpg]

**How I can receive the file with PHP?**

Here is my actual test code:

```
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');
set_exception_handler('myExceptionHandler');

file_putcontents(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'post.txt',
    print_r(array_merge($_REQUEST, $_FILES), true));

$expectedAmountOfDataInBytes = $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
$contents = '';
while(0 < $expectedAmountOfDataInBytes--) {
    $contents .= fread( STDIN, 1 );
}

fclose(STDIN);

file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'file.csv', $contents);


function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'error.txt',
        print_r(array(
            'date'  => date(DateTime::W3C),
            'no'    => $errno,
            'error' => $errstr,
            'file'  => $errfile,
            'line'  => $errline
        ), true), FILE_APPEND);
    die();
}

function myExceptionHandler(Exception $exception) {
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'error.txt',
        print_r(array(
            'date'    => date(DateTime::W3C),
            'code'    => $exception->getCode(),
            'file'    => $exception->getFile(),
            'Line'    => $exception->getLine(),
            'Message' => $exception->getMessage(),
            'Trace'   => $exception->getTrace()
        ), true), FILE_APPEND);
    die();
}
```

My results (post.txt):

```
Array
(
)
```

`file.csv` is empty.

Web server specs:

- Apache/2.2.22
- PHP 5.4.4-14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`http_get_request_body`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-body.php) or [`HttpResponse`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.httpresponse.php) didn't work. And now the PHP doc is outdated. To use it: `\http\Env::getRequestBody()`. See the [doc](http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http).

The solution that worked in the end (PHP 5.4):
Php configuration in the `php.ini`:

```
enable_post_data_reading = 0
```

Or `.htaccess`:

```
php_value enable_post_data_reading 0
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading)

PHP code:

```
$write = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'test.csv','w+');
$read = fopen('php://input','r');
stream_copy_to_stream($read,$write);
```

With [`enable-post-data-reading`](http://php.net/manual/fr/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading), you can use `php://input` with `multipart/form-data` request.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print `$_FILES` & `$_POST`, if both are empty then there is an issue in the Java app code because whenever you'll get file in PHP, then it will be in `$_FILES` or in any key of `$_POST` (base64 encoded or any other encoding).

Comment: TY 4 reply: but `$_REQUEST` containt `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.
I test it independently and they are all empty. I don't understand why I see the data in wireshark and not in PHP.I was thinking that is a problem of PHP/Apache version or no solution for php with these multipart/form-data request.